# codeigniter 4 is returning 1 after include, include_once, require, require_once

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

When i'm using the above mentioned (include, include_once, require, require_once) methods i'm getting the 1 written at the end of every content where i've used it.

Have a look:

```
PHP Code:
<!--Footer Section Starts Here-->
    <?= require_once("elements/footer.php"); ?>
<!--Footer Section Ends Here-->

<!--Bottom CSS and JS Starts Here-->
    <?= include_once("elements/bottom_css_and_js.php"); ?>
<!--Bottom CSS and JS Ends Here-->


Html Output
<div>
    <div>
        <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy;<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> All rights reserved.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="copyright">This template is made with <i class="ion-ios-heart text-red" aria-hidden="true"></i> by <a href="http://localhost:8080/codeigniter4">Localhost</a></p>
    </div>
</div>1

<!--Bottom CSS and JS Starts Here-->
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/codeigniter4/public/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/codeigniter4/public/assets/js/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/codeigniter4/public/assets/bootstrap-footer-19/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/codeigniter4/public/assets/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>1    
<!--Bottom CSS and JS Ends Here-->
```

Comment: You need to provide php code, not browser output. Perhaps you use include so it evaluates to boolean, like in example 4 on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php but it is hard to tell without code.

Comment: I've added the PHP code too

Comment: I think you should replace `<?= require_once("elements/footer.php"); ?>` with `<?php require_once("elements/footer.php"); ?>`. `<?= ?>` is short for `<?php echo ...; ?>` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php). So it returns true which converted to 1 on output.

Comment: Nope, it's not working.

Comment: I thinks its from the environment but it is in the 'production' mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to expand on @sergiy T's comment(answer) and the OP's comment, "Nope it's not working..."

The current code is

```
<!--Footer Section Starts Here-->
    <?= require_once("elements/footer.php"); ?>
<!--Footer Section Ends Here-->

<!--Bottom CSS and JS Starts Here-->
    <?= include_once("elements/bottom_css_and_js.php"); ?>
<!--Bottom CSS and JS Ends Here-->
```

Where you are echoing the result of the calls to require_once and include_once etc due to using **<?=** which is the short code form for **<?php echo**. So you will see the code being "included" and also the result of the function call which is 1.

So you need to remove the echo's as performing a **require** or **include** puts the code inline to be executed/displayed.

So you need to change it to...

```
<!--Footer Section Starts Here-->
    <?php require_once("elements/footer.php"); ?>
<!--Footer Section Ends Here-->

<!--Bottom CSS and JS Starts Here-->
    <?php include_once("elements/bottom_css_and_js.php"); ?>
<!--Bottom CSS and JS Ends Here-->
```

As always its advisable to read what these functions do in php.net

Comment: Thank You, it's working.
I didn't spotted that i'm printing it.